# How to install Bun on Windows without Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: windows, bun

I have just heard about Bun today, and I am eager to learn it.

So, first thing I want to do is to install it in order to try it.

However, I can't find a way to install it on my local machine.

I am using Windows 11.

This is what I found on the [official Readme](https://github.com/Jarred-Sumner/bun#install).

> Install Native: (macOS x64 & Silicon, Linux x64, Windows Subsystem for
> Linux)
>
> curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | bash
>
> Docker: (Linux x64)
>
> docker pull jarredsumner/bun:edge
>
> docker run --rm --init --ulimit memlock=-1:-1 jarredsumner/bun:edge
>
> If using Linux, kernel version 5.6
> or higher is strongly recommended, but the minimum is 5.1.

I already tried

```
curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | bash
```

and it says

> Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
> Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
> https://aka.ms/wslstore curl: (23) Failure writing output to
> destination

So, is there a way to install Bun on Windows without Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Comment: Sadly WSL is required for bun, bun has only just released in beta so Linux, Mac & WSL are only currently supported.

Comment: Why do you want to install bun on Windows without WSL is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: @Mpesiths I just want to use it like how I am using NodeJs. I downloaded it and installed it on my Windows local machine and it works without installing any additional software. It is, in my opinion, cleaner as I am not familiar with WSL.

Comment: Well, Node.js has been years in the wild now. Bun was literally released yesterday (July 6th, 2022). Bun's 'roundabout' installation and limitations only prove how early it is in its life. As a fellow Windows poweruser, I encourage you to try WSL. Is a wonderful tool, to put it short.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Windows support is on [Bun's roadmap](https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/159) (until then, it is only available on *nix systems)

> #### Windows support
>
> - The HTTP client needs a Windows implementation for the syscalls
> - Bun needs test coverage for Windows filepath handling
> - All of bun's dependencies need to compile on Windows
> - Building JavaScriptCore needs to work on Windows and the JIT tiers need to work. I don't know what the current status of this is. WebKit's [bug tracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=145366) suggests it may not have JITs enabled which will likely need some patches to fix it.

Comment: [Bun has just released its official, experimental build for Windows.](https://bun.sh/blog/bun-v1.0#bun-more-thing) The answer may need some round of updates to keep the answer up-to-date with the new versions of Bun.

Comment: @holydragon do you know how to install it? I tried all ways but still get the error `Unsupported platform for bun@1.0.1: wanted {"os":"darwin,linux","arch":"arm64,x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})`

Answer (score 4):

## Experimental support is now available

source: https://bun.sh/docs/installation#windows

> Bun provides a limited, experimental native build for Windows. It is recommended to use Bun within Windows Subsystem for Linux and follow the above instructions. To help catch bugs, the experimental build enables many debugging assertions, which will make the binary slower than what the stable version will be.

To install, paste this into a terminal (PowerShell/cmd):

```bash
# WARNING: No stability is guaranteed on the experimental Windows builds
powershell -c "irm bun.sh/install.ps1|iex"
```

Answer (score 2):

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process -Force; iwr bun.sh/install.ps1 | iex

Exicute this command for this error in windows

Answer (score 1):

U can use the **CodeSpace** from github and install bun. its work normal.

Answer (score -3):

On powershell :

```
wsl --install
```

Then:

```
curl -fsSL https://bun.sh/install | bash
```

More info:
https://github.com/oven-sh/bun/issues/5247#issuecomment-1722171990

Comment: OP specifically asks for a method without WSL.